# How to manipulate Controls in a separate UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba, forms, controls

I have two forms: One, the creatively named `UserForm1` where all my magic happens, and two, `SettingsForm` where the user can adjust some settings. `UserForm1` can open `SettingsForm` and will load any saved settings when initialized in the future.

The issue I'm running into is updating the currently-open `UserForm1` to the newly chosen settings when they're saved over in `SettingsForm`. One of those settings is the default selection in a group of option buttons.

I've tried modifying the loop I use elsewhere to deal with option groups, by changing `Me.Controls` to `[Forms]![exportForm].Controls`, but that's throwing an error. I've never referenced controls in another form before, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing (read: I'm completely clueless). (`defBGU` is a string defined in previous code)

```
Dim opt As Control
For Each opt In [Forms]![exportForm].Controls
    If TypeName(opt) = "OptionButton" Then
        If opt.Name = defBGU Then
            opt.Value = True
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A userform is a class in VBA, and you can (and should) use a variable to access it.
Usually, you write in your code something like

```
UserForm1.Show
```

and that will create a so called *default instance* of the form. But you can also do

```
Dim frm as UserForm1
set frm = new UserForm1
frm.show
```

You can use this variable and access all it's members (`Me` is nothing else than a reference to the instance itself if you are within the form code).

So part of the code in your UserForm1 could look like

```
Dim frmSettings As SettingsForm    ' Declare a variable for the setting form

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' Create a new instance of the setting form
    If frmSettings Is Nothing Then Set frmSettings = New SettingsForm

    ' Do some manipulations and show it
    With frmSettings
        .Caption = "Greetings from " & Me.Name
        .Label1.Caption = "I was set by " & Me.Name
        .TextBox1.Text = "Me too..."
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Well hot dog, that is easy. Thanks!